# Jquery: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I copied the code from one topic. I completely analyzed and understood it. That topic was about assigning the class of the current page (and the html name was searched in links and compared with the current page).

```
function getCurrentLinkFrom(links){
    var curPage = document.URL;
    curPage = curPage.substr(curPage.lastIndexOf("/ ")) ;

    links.each(function(){
        var linkPage = $(this).attr("href");
        linkPage = linkPage.substr(linkPage.lastIndexOf("/"));
        if (curPage == linkPage){
            return $(this);
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentLink = getCurrentLinkFrom($('navbar a')); 
    currentLink.addClass('current_link');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you get to an answer, but will arm you with an important skill at the same time... I have added two logging statements that will show you whether you are getting a match and why.

You only return a value if you find a match, so the error is because you have executed your function without finding a match.

```
function getCurrentLinkFrom(links){
    var curPage = document.URL;
    curPage = curPage.substr(curPage.lastIndexOf("/ ")) ;

    links.each(function(){
        var linkPage = $(this).attr("href");
        linkPage = linkPage.substr(linkPage.lastIndexOf("/"));

        // This will help you see if any match
        console.log(curPage, linkPage);

        if (curPage == linkPage){
            return $(this);
        }
    });

    // This will help you to see when there is no match
    console.log('Not found!', curPage);
};
```

Comment: shouldn't you have the console.log(Not Found... inside the each loop?

Comment: @artSir until you have finished looping, you don't know whether or not you'll find the match. If a match is found, the return statement will short-circuit the function, otherwise it will run to the end, in which case... not found. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your **lastIndexOf** call differs between the two values you're comparing.  The **curPage** one has a space after the slash and the other doesn't.

With that said, you should take a look at [jQuery's filter function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) which would simplify your logic a bit here and follow a better pattern as you'd be calling **addClass** on a jQuery object with (potentially) no matched elements instead of an undefined variable.